# Using Regexp to replace math expression inside Latex File

Tags: regex, latex, replace

I am trying to replace characters inside a math environment with their boldface versions. Unfortunately, these characters occur inside the rest of the text, as well.

My text:

```
text text text text Gtext G G text ....
\begin{align}
f&=gG \\
G &= tG
\end{align}

text textG text $G$ text.
```

---

Every G inside 
    \begin{align} \end{align}
and between the dollar signs 
    $G$
shall be replaced with

\mathbf{G}.

The others shall remain untouched.

I appreciate every idea :)

Thank you

BIG EDIT:
So far, I have a working Program (Python), thanks to the advice and some other findings in stackoverflow.

But the program replaces f.e ***\quad*** to ***\q"replace"ad***. if I want to replace all the ***"u"*** s with ***"replace"***.

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close
import shutil

def replace(file, outputfile, pattern, subst, boundary1, boundary2):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    newfile="tempfile.tmp"
    new_file = open(newfile,'w')
    old_file = open(file)
    inAlign=False
    for line in old_file:
        if boundary1 in line:
              inAlign = True

        if inAlign:
            print line
            print line.replace(pattern, subst)

            new_file.write(line.replace(pattern, subst))
        else:
            new_file.write(line)

        if boundary2 in line:
            inAlign = False;



    #close temp file

    new_file.close()
    close(fh)
    old_file.close()

    shutil.move(newfile,outputfile)

replace("texfile.tex","texfile_copy.tex","G", "\\mathbf{G}", "\\begin{align}", "\\end{align}")
```

Hopefully I got the formatting right...

Comment: why not just use find & replace? its a little bit of work, but the results will be exactly as you want them...

Comment: Strictly "regular" expressions are not powerful enough to parse a context-free language like latex, so you can't do it with certainty. Which is not to say that you can't find a heuristic that will get most cases, especially as you probably don't nest math mode very often.

Comment: RE: why not just use find & replace?

Because that would be a stupid monkeytask.

Comment: maybe you should check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95824/replace-a-character-with-a-string-in-latex

monkeytask: yes... but how long have you spent trying to write this little script? how long would it have taken you to find & replace? I suppose it really depends if this is something you will have to do all the time in exactly the same sequence, or if its just this once...

Comment: Your are of course right with the assumption that writing a script like this takes time (1 hour). But in doing so you do not only learn something, but help others in a similar position, as well.

The script is in no way perfect, but maybe usefull for other similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

This will be hard-to-impossible with regexes alone. What language are you using? It it's perl, there's a module LaTeX::TOM that will help you out a great deal.

However, if you know that your `\begin` and `\end` tags are always on their own line, the following pseudocode would work:

```
foreach (line in file)
    if line.matches( /\\begin{align}/ )
        inAlign = true
    end

    if inAlign
        line.replace( /(G)/\\mathbf{$1}/ )
    else
        line.replace( /\$(G)\$/\$\\mathbf{$1}\$/ )
    end

    if line.matches( /\\end{align}/ )
        inAlign = false;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have never used Perl and I hoped that there is a simpler method.

I need to replace more characters with different commands. The above is just an example. 

"Trying" out Perl and diffing every change would be very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the `G`s within the align blocks:

```
s/(?<=\\begin\{align\})(((?!\\end\{align\}).)*?)G/{$1}\mathbf{G}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

To really solve this, you need to write a parser. Parsing general TeX is a task that might euphemistically be called nontrivial (try running [this file](http://www.maths.abdn.ac.uk/tex/latex_course/obscure.txt) through TeX), but for typical LaTeX math expressions you could start from [matplotlib's parser](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mathtext_api.html#matplotlib.mathtext.MathTextParser) and hack it to do the replacements you want. It still won't be trivial but shouldn't be insurmountable either.